# REST API и групповое редактирование ресурса

Tags: http, rest, best-practice

Запросы к `REST API` принято оформлять следующим образом

```
GET     http://v1/resource/                 // получить все данные ресурса resource
GET     http://v1/resource?fild1=5&Fild2=6  // получить все данные ресурса resource где поле fild1 равно 5 и поле Fild2 равно 6 (количество параметров произвольно)
GET     http://v1/resource?id=5             // получить ресурс resource с айди 5
POST    http://v1/resource/                 // создать ресурс resource со значением поля foo равно bar
        body {foo: 'bar'}
PUT     http://v1/resource?id=5             // отредактировать ресурс resource с айди 5 изменив значение foo на bar
        body {foo: 'bar'}
DELETE  http://v1/resource?id=5             // удалить ресурс resource с айди 5
```

Таким образом мы оформили все `CRUD` операции к нашему ресурсу.

Вопрос в следующем, что если нам нужно изменить не одну запись а 5? Тогда запрос будет иметь следующий вид?

```
PUT http://v1/resource?id=1,2,3,4,5
    body [{foo: 'on_store'},
          {foo: 'on_store'},
          {foo: 'on_store'},
          {foo: 'on_store'},
          {foo: 'on_store'}]
```

Или мне нужно каждый раз обращаться к апи в отдельном запросе?

```
PUT http://v1/resource?id=1
    body {foo: 'on_store'}
PUT http://v1/resource?id=2
    body {foo: 'on_store'}
PUT http://v1/resource?id=3
    body {foo: 'on_store'}
PUT http://v1/resource?id=4
    body {foo: 'on_store'}
PUT http://v1/resource?id=5
    body {foo: 'on_store'}
```

А если таких объектов будет несколько тысяч или десятков тысяч (например изменение статуса в определенном диапазоне товаров, или очень большом перечне товаров где айдишники идут не по порядку)?

Я могу оформить мое апи следующим образом?

```
PUT http://v1/resource
body [{
        id: 1,
        foo: 'on_store'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        foo: 'on_store'
      }, {
        ...
      }, {
        id: n,
        foo: 'on_store'
      }]
```

И зная что это `PUT` передавать `id` объекта который подлежит изменению в теле запроса рядом с полями которые нужно менять?

Comment: В общем и целом последний вариант вполне жизнеспособный.

Comment: Я твердо уверен, что идеология `REST` носит более рекомендательный характер, нежели побудительный. Не стоит слепо и бездумно следовать ей. Я бы выбрал последний вариант, возможно с припиской `batch`(Что тоже выбивается из рекомендации) `PUT http://v1/resource/batch`